# Predict is use different class values Rstudio

Tags: r, predict, nnet

I'm utilizing the titanic dataset to perform some neural network exercise. I split the dataset into train and test. I split the train into 80% and 20% to perform training. After cleaning everything I started training. Here is my code to train.

```
nfit <- train(Survived ~ PassengerId + Pclass + Name + Sex + Age + SibSp +
          Parch + Ticket + Fare + Embarked, 
          data = train.80, method = 'nnet', tuneGrid = grid, 
          skip = TRUE, tuneLength = 2, times = 4)
```

After that I went to predict with this code...

```
pred <- as.numeric(predict(nfit, train.20.survived))
```

The `train.20.survived` DOESN'T have the survived variable on it. Now I want to print my confusion matrix with this code...

```
table(pred, train.20$Survived)
```

And the outcome is as follow....

```
pred  0  1
   1 70 14
   2 17 42
```

If I console out `pred` values are `1` and `2`. How I can force `predict` to match `0` and `1` as in the variable `Survived` so the table can visually match?

Comment: Wow!! Never thought was that simple.

Comment: Post your solution so I can UpVote.

Comment: ha, please feel free to write it up yourself. [I've not looked at the data, but I suspect it may be a factor (which are stored as 1 and 2 for a 2-level factor - loose with terminology im sure), so when you apply as.numeric it converts it to 1 and 2. ]

Comment: You got it right.